# Sails js http post request with content-type: application/json

Tags: json, node.js, sails.js

I would like to understand how to write sails-js controller when http request looks as below, especially here I am trying to send raw-data with `Content-Type: application/json`. Please advise. (I am able to work with POST with form-data, In controller if read req.body I get form-data as key-value pairs of json)

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://localhost:1337/person/create",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json"
  },
  "data": "{'companyID':'DEV','firstName':'Radha','lastName':'A',  'otherIDs': [123,345] }"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Could you be more clear about your problem, I don't really understand the issue or are you requiring just advice?

Comment: My ajax http call looks as mentioned above, now I would like to write sails.js controller to read that http request and write the data part to console. Please advise. The problem I am facing is when my http request sends user-input in form as raw-data.

Comment: Try passing just `dataType: "json"` instead of `"headers": {...}` [reference](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Also in your controller you should just have 
`module.exports = {
 
  action: function(req, res) {
    sails.log.info(req.body);
  }
}
`

Comment: error: Unable to parse HTTP body- error occurred :: 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token \'\n  at Object.parse (native)\n  at parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/skipper/node_modules/connect/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:66:17)\n

Comment: try sending the data as an object and not as string (remove the double apostrophe):
"data": {'companyID':'TGDEV','firstName':'Naga','lastName':'A',  'otherIDs': [123,345] }

Comment: No luck, when sent as object.

Comment: try replacing the data line with this: `data: '{ "companyID":"TGDEV","firstName":"Naga","lastName":"A",  "otherIDs": [123,345] } '`

Comment: Nope! doesn't work that way...

Comment: @VladNeacsu thanks yours comment is answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the data line with this:

`data: '{ "companyID":"TGDEV","firstName":"Naga","lastName":"A", "otherIDs": [123,345] }'`

I think it has something to do with the JSON being invalid. Single quotes are not valid JSON. Check your JSON here if you're unsure, it's a good resource: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score -1):

Replacing the data line with this: `data: '{ "companyID":"TGDEV","firstName":"Naga","lastName":"A", "otherIDs": [123,345] } '`